# Magento 2 : override customer grid collection

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, customer-grid

I want to override customer grid collection to filter by customer group. How to add customer group filter on Customer grid?

Answer (score 2):

By default customer group exist in grid collection filter. You just need to enable `group` from grid `columns` setting from right top corner of grid.

Comment: I don't want to filter manually.Actually, i want to display customers for a specific group in the grid.

Comment: override Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection class and add this code:    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
    
            $this->addFieldToFilter('group_id','3');
    
             parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }

Comment: and how to call this Collection in my new module please